# Do vector also initialise primitive types in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I know that when working with vectors and when knowing the size of a vector beforehand (tho it might get extended), one should use `myVector.reserve(# objects)` instead of `vector<object> myVector(# objects)` since the latter does a lot of unnecessary copies as it actually initialises the objects.

Does the same hold for primitive types like `int`, meaning does `vector<int> vec(10)` initialises 10 integers with 0?

Comment: *"since the latter does a lot of unnecessary copies"* - it hasn't been specified to copy anything for about 10 years now.

Comment: For primitive types it is perfectly valid to not set them to 0 and just reserve their memory. I am not 100% certain but I believe that this is implementation defined - meaning it or might not be set to 0 depending on what STL implementors chose to do.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ALX23z I believe it must set them to 0. It's forced by [`std::allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct), and by substituting the allocator you can get rid of this initialization.

Comment: Be careful, `reserve` does not do the same thing thing as constructor a pre-sized vector. You can't access any elements if you just do `reserve`, although it might look like it works at first. If you use `vector<int> v; v.reserve(10);` you still have an empty vector and `v[0]` would still be out of bounds. If you try to use `reserve` as an alternative, you still need to `resize` or otherwise insert elements, which usually zero initializes (unless you already know the value of each element you want to insert).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I always use (I'm started learning C++ a few days ago and saw this in a video) `myVector.emplace_back(element)` after having reserved the space. So is reserving space really more efficient that doing `vector<object> myVector(#objects)` ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux forget my first sentence.

Comment: @HerkulesOl Your approach is fine. But skipping the zero initialization won't be a significant gain, probably. The reason to use `reserve` it to avoid having to reallocate the underlying array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):
[image]

Which has the description:

> 4. Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of
>    T. No copies are made.

So yes, if you write `vector<int> vec(10)`, it will default *construct* 10 integers with value 0.